# Jsoup - Parsing a HTML file with charset iso-8859-1

Tags: java, character-encoding, html-parsing, jsoup, iso-8859-1

I am having trouble with special characters and `charset = iso-8859-1`.
The same code that I use here works fine with UTF-8, so I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

Here is the code:

```
File input = new File("/users/marcioapf/example.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "iso-8859-1", "");
Elements elements = doc.select("span.DEPUTADO")  ;
System.out.println(elements.toString());
```

Here is the output:

```
<span style="margin-left: 8px; width: auto !important;" class="DEPUTADO">Jo&atilde;ozinho Pereira</span> 
<span style="margin-left: 8px; width: auto !important;" class="DEPUTADO">Isnaldo Bulh&otilde;es</span> 
<span style="margin-left: 8px; width: auto !important;" class="DEPUTADO">Antonio Albuquerque</span> 
<span style="margin-left: 8px; width: auto !important;" class="DEPUTADO">Jeferson Morais</span> 
<span style="margin-left: 8px; width: auto !important;" class="DEPUTADO">In&aacute;cio Loiola</span>
```

Here is how it should be:

```
<span style="margin-left: 8px; width: auto !important;" class="DEPUTADO">Joãozinho Pereira</span> 
<span style="margin-left: 8px; width: auto !important;" class="DEPUTADO">Isnaldo Bulhões</span> 
<span style="margin-left: 8px; width: auto !important;" class="DEPUTADO">Antonio Albuquerque</span> 
<span style="margin-left: 8px; width: auto !important;" class="DEPUTADO">Jeferson Morais</span> 
<span style="margin-left: 8px; width: auto !important;" class="DEPUTADO">Inácio Loiola</span>
```

How I can I fix it?

Comment: What happens if you first load the entire file into memory and then process it with `Jsoup.parse(String)` method? Besides, the output is technically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `EscapeMode.xhtml` will give you output without entities.
Try this code

```
  File input = new File("/users/marcioapf/example.html");
  Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "iso-8859-1", "");
  doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml);
  Elements elements = doc.select("span.DEPUTADO")  ;
  System.out.println(elements.toString());
```